# spring webclient caching OAuth token

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-webclient

Can we cache the OAuth token using spring webclient?, i have configured webclient as below, it is fetching the token for every request, is there any spring way to cache the token and refreshed only after expiry automatically.

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager clientManager(
       @Qualifier("proxyCpClientRegistrationRepository") ClientRegistrationRepository proxyCpClientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .clientCredentials()
                    .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    proxyCpClientRegistrationRepository, clientService);
   // authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(new DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(
            new RefreshTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(),
            new ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider()));

    return authorizedClientManager;
}

   @Bean
    public WebClient client(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager proxyCpAuthorizedClientManager) {

    var oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(proxyCpAuthorizedClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(CP_CLIENT);

    return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration())
            .baseUrl(getUrl()).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "service").build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I couldn't find a property you set for auto config. BUT this was a viable solution at least. See below:

**Make a new class that you can wrap authorizedClientManager with**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizeRequest;

public class CachingOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CachingOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.class);

    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager delegate;

    public CachingOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "oauth2AuthorizedClients", key = "#authorizeRequest.clientRegistrationId + ':' + #authorizeRequest.principal.name")
    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorize(OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest) {
        logger.info("Getting OAuth token...");
        return delegate.authorize(authorizeRequest);
    }

}
```

**Update your return to be:**

```
return new CachingOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(authorizedClientManager);
```

**Make a bean:**

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
   return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
}
```

**Make sure to have**

```
@EnableCaching
//and
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
```